# How to implement cascade='delete' in NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I was trying to use cascading delete, but couldn't find enough documentation to get my answers.

I have one parent class and two child classes dependent on that. When I delete parent it should delete the other two child classes as well.

Questions:

1. Where do I need to put the set and key thing (in parent hbm file or in two child hbm files)?
2. And if  I need to put in parent hbm, do I need to put two set for each of the child classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. You need to use **all-delete-orphan** cascade settings on both child mappings in parent hbm file.

Reference found [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping), [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-graphs) and [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild-cascades).

Comment: thnx for the info, I have defined the two sets into my parent hbm file.But im getting this error "XML validation error: The 'name' attribute is not declared". This error im getting where i have defined the key name for the first set.But I already have a FK relationship between the parent and the 1st child.